# How to insert a list at a specific index?

Tags: python, list

I got a list

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

and a list of list

```
 b=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

and I want to insert a into b at index 1 so b becomes

```
 b=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
```

How do I do that?If I use insert it won't work because I can only insert an item not a list?

EDIT:I realised insert can be used for lists as well.Thanks.

Comment: "If I use insert it won't work because I can only insert an item not a list?" Did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list.insert` which takes the `index` as the first argument

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> b.insert(1, a)
>>> b
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing:

```
b=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]
a = [1, 2, 3]
final_list = b[:1]+[a]+b[1:]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```